# sh: 1: start-server-and-test: Permission denied

Tags: node.js, git, cypress, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to create a pipeline on git in combination with my cypress tests. Whenever I try to do this is ends with the error `sh: 1: start-server-and-test: Permission denied`. I've been googling for an hour but can't seem to figure out what is wrong. (Also new to Git CI so that makes it all a lost harder.)

My package.json scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "npx webpack-cli",
    "build:dev": "npx webpack-cli --mode=development",
    "start": "npx webpack serve",
    "watch": "npx webpack serve",
    "lint": "npx eslint src/**.js src/js/**.js",
    "cy:test": "npx cypress run",
    "test:headless": "npx cypress run --spec cypress/integration/ToDo_tests.js",
    "test": "start-server-and-test start http-get://localhost:8080 test:headless"
  },
```

My Git CI:

```
image: node:latest

stages:     
  - test

cypress-test-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd frontend-webpack/
    - echo "Testing frontend with Cypress"
    - npm config set user 0
    - npm config set unsafe-perm true
    - npm run test
    - echo "Testing complete"
```

The output of the failed pipeline:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.9.0~beta.68.g1283960c (1283960c)
  on green-5.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default xS6Vzpvo
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:34
Using Docker executor with image node:latest ...
Pulling docker image node:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:20c0a0be5115616fa6d27d6c72aefe8663340fd7f5fce9bc9d62728b2efe7a75 for node:latest with digest node@sha256:0b553d28086d90b9b3be3339beb97401f8c0a83c17230a37ad99ff88fdad3b3f ...
Preparing environment
00:03
Running on runner-xs6vzpvo-project-34382765-concurrent-0 via runner-xs6vzpvo-shared-1649328236-cb09d98a...
Getting source from Git repository
00:11
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/saxion.nl/hbo-ict/development-tools/web/38/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 387cff6f as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:02
Using docker image sha256:20c0a0be5115616fa6d27d6c72aefe8663340fd7f5fce9bc9d62728b2efe7a75 for node:latest with digest node@sha256:0b553d28086d90b9b3be3339beb97401f8c0a83c17230a37ad99ff88fdad3b3f ...
$ cd frontend-webpack/
$ echo "Testing frontend with Cypress"
Testing frontend with Cypress
$ npm config set user 0
$ npm config set unsafe-perm true
$ npm run test
> seminar-week5-client@1.0.0 test
> start-server-and-test start http://localhost:8080 test:headless
sh: 1: start-server-and-test: Permission denied
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried running `chmod +x` on your `start-server-and-test` script as part of your CI job?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` should be like:

```
stages:
  - test

e2e-test:
  image: cypress/browsers:node16.14.0-slim-chrome99-ff97
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run test
```

And I suggest you to use wait-on instead of start-server-and-test, for that, first install wait-on dependence with `npm i wait-on` and change your test script in package.json to: `"test":"npm run start && wait-on http://localhost:8080 && npm run test:headless`"

Comment: Thanks for the help! And yeah I've been looking at wait-on as well, but my study requires me to use start-server-and-test, no idea why

Comment: Cool, I think you can just replace `wait-on` in my example with `start-server-and-test` I think this should work